# Which advertisment network should i use for my app (in 2014)?

Tags: android, ads

I am planning to launch a free app soon, but I am a student I want to get some money for collage so i want to implement ads in my app, but which network should I use? There are alot threads already on this topic, but the are all from some years ago. So here is my question. Which is the most userfriendly and easiest advertisment network? I dont want to seem stingy but i also want to know which pays the best.

Thanks up front!

Comment: The answer is depends on your app/game kind, language, audience. There is a lot of factor.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about advertising and marketing and not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with google their own advertisment system and their easy to use API's

you can find more information about mobile ads here on the android developer website

https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/ads.html

and here is a link to AdMob sign up page

https://apps.admob.com/admob/signup?